# Zen cart using attribute price factor on top of other attribute prices

Tags: php, zen-cart

I've inherited a Zen cart shop (1.3.9h), it's been hacked quite (even in the core in places) so upgrading it isn't an option. I have set it up as follows:

product price: 0
product priced by attributes: yes

---

large option price: 600
large option included in base price: true

small option price: 200
small option included in base price: true

---

additional feature price: 60
additional feature included in base price: true

no additional feature price: 0
no additional feature included in base price: true

---

made with expensive material price factor: 1.2
made with expensive material price offset: 1

---

I get the following results:

large, normal material, no additional features: £600 - as expected
large, normal material, additional feature: £660 - as expected
large, expensive material, no additional features: £633.33 - I would expect £720 (600 * 1.2)
large, expensive, additional feature: £693.33 -I would expect £792 ((600+60) * 1.2)

I can't understand why it would do this, it just seems that using any price factors does not work.

Comment: can you please share URL or something like that?

Comment: Hi, the site is only on a local dev server at the moment so I'm afraid I can't share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The price-factor does not apply to the aggregate of all attribute selection choices.

It applies only to the lowest possible price (ie: take the lowest possible price of each Option Name group and add those to determine lowest-possible. Price-Factor will apply to that value).